# Creating an AWS deployment package for Python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to follow [AWS's tutorial: Create a Deployment Package (Python)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python) so I can execute my Lambda function but I'm having trouble understanding the steps. Here are the steps listed from the tutorial:

1 - Open a text editor, and copy the following code:

...

2 - Save the file as CreateThumbnail.py.

So I save the file as `CreateThumbnail.py` - but where do I save the file? In my project directory?

3 - If your source code is on a local host, copy it over.

```
scp -i key.pem /path/to/my_code.py ec2-user@public-ip-address:~/CreateThumbnail.py
```

What is `/path/to/my_code.py` supposed to point to? A `.py` file in my project directory? Which file?

What is `ec2-user@public-ip-address`? What do I substitue `ec2-user` and `public-ip-address` for? Is `public-ip-address` the IP address of my website?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ec2-user is the default user AWS EC2 machines assign when you spin them up. You use the key.pem to log into the EC2 machine as ec2-user. The public ip address is the public ip address that AWS EC2 assigns to it's instance when you spin up a machine and allow it to assign a public ip address (i.e. an address that is routable over the public internet).

You need to substitute the  in the tutorial with the ip address that you can find by going to your EC2 Console, and selecting the machine that you want to copy the file to. The console will show you details associated with the Machine, one of which is the public ip address. You then substitute the ip address listed here in place of .

/path/to/my_code.py is the absolute path of the file "my_code.py" on your local machine (i.e. the path where my_code.py file is). As you are using scp (secure copy utility). When you issue the command you are saying copy the file at /path/to/my_code.py (file my_code.py) to the remote machine (your EC2 instance) and place it in the home directory of ec2-user on the server as a file called "CreateThumbnail.py"

Comment: Thanks. So I need to create a AWS EC2 instance? It doesn't say that in the tutorial though?: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html

Comment: Or you can follow the steps locally. I presume you are using a windows machine? So will be easier to just create an Amazon EC2 Linux Machine to follow the steps outlined in that tutorial. Otherwise you can do it on your local machine, but you won't be able to follow those instructions on your windows machine without installing something such as git bash and chocolatey etc.